# Preferred validations in ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Which validations are preferred : client side(using Javascript) or serverside (using validation controls in C# asp.net)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should *always* validate on the server. Client-side validation is fine to enhance the user experience, but anything that has come from the client is potentially dirty and should be validated on the sever again, as your server-side code is not vulnerable to malicious user manipulations (at least, not in the same way that client-side code is).

**Always finally validate on the server!!**

Comment: No probs :) But **always validate on the server**!! haha

Answer (score 1):

Both.

> JavaScript is important because it prevents invalid postbacks to
>   server.
>
> Server-side is important if client disabled JavaScript from browser
>   than  JavaScript validation bypass.

I also recommend you to make validation at database level also. for reliability.

Answer (score 1):

both are good, at minimum server side validation is a must. As client might have javascript disabled on the browser

> **Reason you shouldn't rely on client side validation**

- The end user could have javascript switched off
- The data could be sent directly to your server by someone who's not
  even using your site, with a custom app designed to do so
- A Javascript error on your page (caused by any number of things)
  could result in some, but not all, of your validation running

Answer (score 1):

You should perform validations at server side as well as client side.Client side validations increase interactivity of your applications.In other words make your application more user friendly.However client side validations may have their shortcomings , if your user disables javascript , then he could very well enter non sense data values and send them  to your server.You dont want this to happen.For that purpose you need to perform server side validations.Server side  validation controls filter the input and make sure proper data is entered.There are good validation controls Asp.Net offers.You could very well utilize them.
I recommend you to use both client as well as server side validation for a blend of interactivity and protection.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The basic validation such as the emptiness of the fields, valid emails, number, strings or dates should be done at the client side, but you should always validate at the server for any potential hacking like cross site scripting or tags (php tags for example) and to make more and more secure always use stored procedures and also make sure to have a function that replaces "'" by this """ or <> by empty string and any other dangerous characters.